# asp.net mvc redirect to an action of another controler from a ajax invoked action which return a partial view

Tags: ajax, redirect, model-view-controller

how to redirect to an action of another controler from an ajax invoked get action which return a partial view in normal case.

within the ajax invoked action, on my exception block, i am looking to redirect to my error controller's error action. but for the time the error view is loaded within a div(#qstn-type-box) which normally loads partial view, when there is no error.

```
$("#qstn-type-box").load('@(Url.Action("GetQuestionbyType", "question",null, Request.Url.Scheme))?type=' + Type + '&Id=' + Id);
```